# Python Pandas ix timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I´ve got a pandas dataframe form csv file with the following index

```
Time stamp                   SOG    Altitude
2015-03-11T08:49:53.000Z        0   20
2015-03-11T08:49:42.000Z        0   19
2015-03-11T08:49:32.000Z        0   24
.....
```

I´d like to use ix for slicing the dataframe but I need to enter just hours and minute in the index, not the exact value.

For example

```
df3= df.ix['2015-03-11T08:49':'2015-03-11T08:52',['SOG','Altitude' ]]
```

Should I use regular expresions or has Pandas a way to do that ?

**Note**: As of Pandas v0.20, `.ix` [indexer is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix) in favour of `.iloc` / `.loc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the `Time stamp` a DatetimeIndex, then you could use the [`DataFrame.between_time` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
import io
import pandas as pd

text = '''\
Time stamp                   SOG    Altitude
2015-03-11T08:49:53.000Z        0   20
2015-03-11T08:49:42.000Z        0   19
2015-03-11T08:49:32.000Z        0   24'''

df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(text), sep='\s{2,}')
df['Time stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time stamp'])
df = df.set_index(['Time stamp'])
df.between_time('8:49:32', '8:49:52')
```

yields

```
                     SOG  Altitude
Time stamp                        
2015-03-11 08:49:42    0        19
2015-03-11 08:49:32    0        24
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the index to Pandas timestamps.

```
df.index = [pd.Timestamp(ts) for ts in df.index]
```

Then your .ix indexing should work as you'd expect.